# computed property based on relationship

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

I'm doing an online course platform, I have the `users` table and `lessons`

I need to check when a user attended a class, so I made a belongsToMany relationship and I have the `lesson_views` table that holds the user id and the class id he attended

so in the listing, in Lesson's model I'd like to do something like

```
static get computed() {
  return ['viewed']
}

getViewed({id, auth}) {
  const viewed = await Database.table('lesson_views')
  .where({ lesosn_id: id, user_id: auth.user.id })

  return (viewed) ? true : false
}
```

but I know it is not possible to query `auth` within a Model.

So how in the lesson listing can I tell which lesson the user has already attended?

Comment: Call `getViewed()` from your controller and pass in `auth`. As a side note, if you want to return a list of viewed lessons, matching only `user_id` should suffice.

Comment: @DafangCao and how can i connect `getViewed()` to my controller? How to receive the `user_id` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

after getting data from `lesson_views` table convert into json  like this

- `const LessonView = use('App/Models/LessonView')`.
   i hope this is your model name
- after this you find user like this 
  `const lessonviewdata = await LessonView.findBy('user_id',1)`
- then convert into json 
  `const jsondata = lessonviewdata.toJSON()`
- then get **viewed**
  `console.log(jsondata.viewed)`